# I can redirect to a different route, but that route doesn't work if I refresh the browser

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Through `$router.push({ path:`/week/${year}/${month}/${day}/`})` I can successfully route/move (not sure about what term to use here) to a different route, with the URL correctly updating.

However once there, if I refresh the browser, the routed component becomes empty (and no console error).

Any idea what's going on here?

Here's my router code:

```
let router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    ...
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: '/home',
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/week/:year/:month/:day',
      component: Home,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure whichever server that you are using to handle the router as you are using history mode.

I will post the sample configuration for `Apache` and `Nginx` since they are most commonly used.

---

**Apache**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

---

**Nginx**

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

---

Additional information can be found on the official [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations).

Comment: Thanks! I'm not using Apache, just the default Webpack simple / Vue CLI... So I guess I need to use the "Native Node.js" snippet correct? Any idea where that snippet should go?

Comment: Are you using `express` as your server? From the docs, you will need a middleware to handle it. I am not sure how to go about that as I have never tried this before.